# HTML dynamic number of Checkboxes

Tags: html

i want to make a table with checkboxes (each for breakfast, lunch, dinner). Above the table i can chose the date for my journey, for example from 22.05.17  till 25.05.17. and i want to have one row with breakfast, lunch, dinner for every day(5 in my example). And when i click on lunch for example, i can do something, like inkrement my journeycost. For example 5€ for each clicked lunch checkbox. I dont know to solve any of these 2 problems. 
Greetings

PS: the table is working but not the dynamic number of rows with the boxes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isyjc.png)

Comment: Please post an example or your code so we can help

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sure:  first: this is the code for the table from the image above. 
and i want to make this dynamic for the number of days resulting from the second code example.

```
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">TT.MM.JJJJ</th>
          <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">8 Stunden</span></td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">TT.MM.JJJJ</th>
          <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">24 Stunden</span></td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">TT.MM.JJJJ</th>
          <td><span class="badge badge-pill badge-default">8 Stunden</span></td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox m-0">
              <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
              <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>v
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <hr>
  </div>
```

the next code segment is for choosing the journey dates (from when to when) and i want to use the number of days the journey will be, to create as many rows for my checkboxes(each wih breakfast, dinner and lunch)

```
 <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Reisebeginn (Datum, Uhrzeit)</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="flatpickr1" placeholder="Start" name="start" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Reiseende (Datum, Uhrzeit)</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="flatpickr2" placeholder="Ende" name="start" />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Place it in your question, otherwise people might think you've already found an answer to your own question.